# Escutar class durante o carregamento da pagina

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Preciso criar uma função ou script que ao carregar a pagina o mesmo detecte quais elementos tem uma classe especifica e execute a programação definida... no caso seria para ocultar o conteúdo...

só que o problema esta sendo fazer ele executar isso em tempo real.. assim que o elemento é criado..

estou tentando fazer isso com javascript mas vale php tbm.. 
se alguém conseguir me ajudar...

```
var hid = document.querySelectorAll('.esconde')
for (var i = 0; i <= hid.length; i++) {
    hid[i].innerHTML = " ";
}
```

Este código faz o que quero porem somente apos o carregamento da pagina.. preciso que isso aconteça durante o carregamento

Comment: O melhor seria fazeres isso com CSS! `.esconde {display: none;}` Assim a página nunca mostra esses elementos.

Comment: no posso fazer dessa forma pq quebra o layout

Comment: Qual é a diferença de fazer com CSS e como procuras _"preciso que isso aconteça durante o carregamento"_?